# Override show.html.twig in SonataClassificationBundle/CategoryAdmin

Tags: symfony, twig, overriding, sonata-admin, symfony-3.2

I'm trying to override  `show.html.twig` in the context of `SonataClassificationBundle/CategoryAdmin`

I've tried putting it in `/app/Resources/SonataClassificationBundle/views/CategoryAdmin/show.html.twig` but it doesn't work.

I'm using Symfony 3.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the **show.html.twig** file in original bundle directory.

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataClassificationBundle/tree/3.x/Resources/views/CategoryAdmin

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to say. the original file is here:
/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/show.html.twig

All the admin services in sonata-admin use it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution (almost one):

I've editd CategoryAdmin overrideing this function:

```
class CategoryAdmin extends BaseCategoryAdmin
{
    public function getTemplate($name) {
        if ($name == 'show') {
            return 'ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:CategoryAdmin:show.html.twig';
        } else {
            return parent::getTemplate($name);
        }

    }
}
```